# How to remove elements from DOM using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

With javascript, I am trying to remove and delete elements in the ion-list (or each of the individual ion-item elements) but I'm not able to do so. The HTML is dynamically generated.

This is the error I get when I uncomment the JS:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined
```

At the very least, I'd like to be able to remove the images in DOM.

Any advice on how to do this?

Javascript:

```
function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    // while(elements.length > 0){
    //     elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    // }
    console.log(elements);
}

removeElementsByClass('image');
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="collection-repeat-container" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); height: 550px; width: 451px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/c1f8c181025553297b6939e152b9952e/tumblr_mudb5hymz41r1thfzo6_1280.jpg" class="image" style="height: 450px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;A beautiful place because of the sound the wind makes as it blows through the thick bamboo grove.</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item>

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 549px, 0px); height: 550px; width: 451px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="http://209.205.207.20/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/31.jpg" class="image" style="height: 450px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;The dense growth of conifers in the forest blocks out most of the light inside the forest.</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item>

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 1098px, 0px); height: 550px; width: 451px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="http://209.205.207.20/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/41.jpg" class="image" style="height: 450px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;Vast farmlands get covered in golden, yellow rapeseed flowers stretching as far as the eyes can see.</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item>

  <ion-item collection-repeat="item in locations" style="padding: 0px 0px 15px; border: 0px; transform: translate3d(-9999px, -9999px, 0px); height: 0px; width: 0px;" class="item">



    <!-- START OF IMAGE -->
    <div class="item item-image">
      <a on-tap="getMap($index)" class="disable-user-behavior">
        <img src="{{item.imageLink}}" class="image" style="height: {{windowWidth}}px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF IMAGE -->

    <div class="item item-text-wrap" style="border-color:white; padding-bottom:25px;">
      <label class="positive">
        <i class="ion-information-circled positive"></i>
      </label>

        <label style="font-family:'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" class="ng-binding">&nbsp;{{item.Fact}}</label>

    </div>


  </ion-item></div>


</div></ion-list>
```

Comment: Is your code not working when you uncomment it? Is any of that HTML dynamically generated?

Comment: What does the console log show? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes, the HTML is dynamically generated. I've placed the error I get in the console above now.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me on FF and Chrome.

Comment: @MrLister In general, incorrect: we would be dealing with an (object implementing the) `NodeList` (interface) here, not an `Array` instance. In a `NodeList`, items are re-arranged if one is deleted. However, it is possible that the `document.getElementsByClassName` method that the OP uses is a shim, in which case it may return a reference to an `Array` instance which does not work like a `NodeList` (DOM-native `document.getElementsByClassName` is not available in IE < 9 and IE 9 in Compatibility Mode, for example); and *that* case you would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using es6, below will work for you:

```
function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    Array.from(elements).forEach(el => {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
    console.log(elements);
}

removeElementsByClass('image');
```

And using es5, this will work:

```
function removeElementsByClass(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    [].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(el) {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
    console.log(elements);
}

removeElementsByClass('image');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sr2ukxjv/1/)**

Your code only finds the first element in the collection which will fail for the second iteration at latest. Above code loops through all elements and will remove the correct one for you!

Comment: Why `[].slice.call(elements).forEach` instead of simply `[].forEach.call(elements`?

Comment: Well, I think because I'm used to it that way. @torazaburo Is there any better about using the way you would write it?

Comment: Yes, it's shorter and cleaner.

Comment: His code works because `getElementsByClassName` actually returns a live list, which mutates every time he removes the child.

Comment: @MinusFour His code works *if* his `getElementsByClassName` returns a reference to a `NodeList`. That it does not, indicates a bad shim returning an `Array`, so the approach in the answer is overkill.